# Identify Health Centre Location using machine learning ( Optimisation )

Tags: r, geolocation, optimization, machine-learning

I am trying to identify locations of where new health centres could be built in the country using Machine Learning (optimisation) and R programming language. I currently have the latitude and longitude of current health centres. I was looking at this tutorial:

https://www.dataplusscience.com/GeoOptTabInstructions.html

and I'm not sure if its adequate for what Im trying to do. I was also looking at the Bayesian algorithm as well.

Any thoughts on which way to proceed?

Comment: This is the "location-allocation" problem. Why restrict yourself to machine learning approaches? Have you researched the problem? There's lots of literature on it. Not sure if there's implementations in R but it will depend on your application a lot. A full answer here would be way too long.